# Send a blob from downloaded pdf back to rest

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, jersey, blob

I've downloaded a pdf from a Jersey GET service that produces "application/pdf", in JS I set the response in a new Blob(), retrieved an url from createObjectURL and displayed the pdf in the page. Now how can I reverse the process and return the same pdf back to a POST service?

I've managed to retrieve the Blob back from the objectUrl with:

```
var blob = await fetch(documentUtils.getDocumentURL()).then(r => r.blob());
```

but now I don't know how to configure the ajax call and how to annotate the jersey POST service